# Random Distorted / Garbled Sound In Windows XP

Tags: laptop, audio, hp-pavilion, distortion

I have laptop **Pavilion dv5282** and sometimes sound gets garbled / distorted. [Listen to this sound file](http://www.filetolink.com/1b0b6f13). Note that this happens only when music/video is playing, i mean only when there should be any sound coming off i.e sound card not idle. I had this problem in the beginning when i purchased laptop, but as a few years passed by, problem disappeared. 2 weeks ago i formatted and reinstalled Windows XP and now this problem came up again. Should i put headphones on, or listen through built-in speakers, problem is still there which should indicate that the problem is with sound card or drivers. When i am watching online video, the problem happens, but i have noticed that if i start playing music in Winamp, the problem disappears, until i stop music from playing.

Mostly i have noticed this problem mostly occurs after **Stand By** mode.What should i do to fix this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to update your drivers to the latest version? Maybe during your last install this happened at some point and fixed the problems.

Comment: My driver version is 3.23.0.0 but the updated driver version is 3.23.0.0 A. Here is its description: http://i.imgur.com/dHV0x.png

Look on description. Do you think this should fix the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XP go to Control Panel... Performance and Maintenance... System... Hardware...Device Manager...

Click on the IDE ATA/ATAPI Controllers to see a list of your Primary and Secondary Channels. Right click on each and select Properties... Under the Advanced Settings check to see if the Transfer mode is set to DMA if available and that the Current Transfer Mode is NOT PIO. If it is PIO Right click the drive channel in the device list and click Uninstall! This might seem a LITTLE RADICAL, but it will fix the problem.

After you have uninstalled the drive channel, Windows will want to Restart your computer. During that time, it will reset to a DMA setting in most cases. If it does not, then you are stuck with PIO.

I think that my DMA problem was created when I installed a second hard drive. Oddly the Primary was PIO and the newer drive was already set to DMA.

Give it a try! It worked wonders for my sound and the darn thing runs a little faster too!